# Which properties of the pullback/restriction functor imply surjectivity of a ring homomorphism

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $f:R\to S$ be a homomorhpism of (noncommutative) algebras over some field k (say the complex numbers) and let $F:Rep(S)\to Rep(R)$ be the corresponding functor between the categories of finite-dimensional representations, given by pullback. Which properties of $F$ imply that $f$ is surjective?

It seems that fully faithful is not enough, and one might suspect that projectives mapping to projectives or the image being a Serre subcategory might be sufficient. I have found many results in the other direction, for example the standard (counter-)example $\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Q}$.

The application I have in mind are algebra $S,R$ that are free of finite rank over a common commutative subalgebra, in order to deduce $f$ is actually bijective. Just in case this assumption makes things easier.

I am happy for any comment or literature recommendation. Thanks.

Comment: What is $\operatorname{Rep}(R)$?

Comment: Fully faithful is equivalent to epimorphism in the category of rings.

Comment: Thank you for the comment...! Indeed, using the keyword "epimorphism" I found statements that if the epimorhpism F is finite, then it is surjective, and if the epimorphism F is flat, then it is surjective. If you have a book recommendation for these or similar facts, please let me know.

Comment: What is a finite dimensional representation of a ring?

Comment: I formulated more carefully,  thanks for the comments.

Comment: I removed the "calculus-of-functors" tag as it does not seem relevant to the question.

Comment: What if $R$ and $S$ have no nonzero finite dimensional representations? Then $F$ is the zero functor between zero categories, whether or not $f$ is surjective.